# All Input Methods frozen, how to edit .profile file

Tags: 20.04, startup, touchscreen, .profile

I was trying to permanently disable the touchscreen on my ubuntu 20 by writing the following code in my .profile file :

```
xinput disable $16  // for my touchscreen device
```

Now after rebooting all of my input devices (touchpad, external mouse, keyboard, touchscreen) don't work. How can I delete that specific line in my .profile file with this setup??

**Please Please Help!**

Comment: Grab your bootable USB installation media, choose “Try Ubuntu”, mount your partition, and edit he file.

Comment: I just deleted that line and unmounted the disk and started my normal OS again. The issue still exists - has it got something to do with cache?

Comment: Update : Finally got this to work! Apart from steps mentioned by Matigo, I had to run bin/bash $.profile path in order to undo changes made by previous source command. @matigo - could you add your comment as an answer so that I accept it as solution? Thanks a lot!